# What can I do with leftover "Sweet and sticky" marinade?

Tags: marinade

I've been cooking [SWEET ‘N STICKY BAKED CHICKEN DRUMSTICKS](http://www.thecomfortofcooking.com/2011/02/sweet-n-sticky-baked-chicken-drumsticks.html), though instead of marinading the chicken, and baking it separately while reducing the marinade, I've been cooking the chicken with the marinade together, effectively half boiling it, half baking it.

The result is quite satisfying but I'm left with a half a Pyrex roaster of marinade.

Can I reuse that in a completely different dish instead of washing it down the drain ? (First thing that came to mind was a salad to use as a dressing)

Comment: There are several factors to consider: How long after the chicken comes out of the oven do you plan to use the sauce? How do you plan to store it if there is a significant period of time in between? Also, the way you are doing it makes this a different issue than reusing a marinade, as theoretically, you are fully cooking it and not and not holding raw chicken in it for an extended period of time.

Comment: If you re-use it, do it quickly.  There are meat juices in it, so it could become unsafe after a few days if you didn't freeze it.  I'd probably cut up some potatoes, toss them in the sauce, then spread on a sheet pan and bake.  (but do it on parchment paper or silicone, as the sugars could fuse everything to the pan).  Or actually reduce it and use it as a sauce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main concern with re-using anything that has come into contact with chicken is salmonella, however as you are talking about using marinade that has been cooked you shouldn't have any safety concerns, so you can use it in a different dish.

As for what to do with it that's hard to say for sure, it depends on how thick it is. If it's really baked on then you're likely to find that all the goodness has been cooked out of it and it will have a burnt taste and not much else. If it's more of a gel and tastes good you could use it for a variety of things, anywhere you'd use barbecue sauce basically, for instance:

- Dipping sauce for fries, breads, etc
- Substitute pizza sauce
- Sauce for burgers

Comment: Its more watery than anything else. "Use it as barbecue sauce" thanks. :)